# How to add data to a json file?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have this json file (it is a mock object that works as a database for users):

```
[
  {
    "id": "0",
    "username": "aaaaaaaaa",
    "password": "xxxxxxxxx",
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "username": "bbbbbbbbb",
    "password": "yyyyyyyyy",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "username": "ccccccccc",
    "password": "zzzzzzzzz",
  }
]
```

I need to add new users in this json file. 
I tryed to use the fs.appendFile function, but it append the user after the square bracket.

How can I do it?

Comment: parse the JSON, then append to the array, and finally write the whole file

Comment: May I suggest reading the whole file, adding your data, and then writing the whole thing back?

Comment: @xRobot Then using a DB would be the right option.

Comment: Well "thousands of users" isn't really that much .. so it only depends on how often the operation is done as far as if there will be a 'performance' issue. Of course an actual database may be useful/better for other reasons..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load your json file in memory, update your array and then save it back. Something like:

```
var users = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('yourfile.json', 'utf8'));
users.push({
    "id": "10",
    "username": "blabla",
    "password": "passpass",
});
fs.writeFileSync('yourfile.json', JSON.stringify(users));
```

Comment: In this case the square brackets are not added. How could I add it ?

Comment: @xRobot The square brackets are correctly added, this is the output after running my code: `[{"id":"0","username":"aaaaaaaaa","password":"xxxxxxxxx"},{"id":"1","username":"bbbbbbbbb","password":"yyyyyyyyy"},{"id":"2","username":"ccccccccc","password":"zzzzzzzzz"},{"id":"10","username":"blabla","password":"passpass"}]`